# How to write to new safari window

Tags: javascript, html, dom, safari

I open a new safari window using:

```
safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url = myUrl;
```

How do I modify the dom of the page in the new window?
I need to modify an anchor in the new window from:

```
<a href="foo" class="bar"></a>
```

to:

```
<a href="fizz" class="buzz"></a>
```

Or alternatively, I just need a way to insert:

`<a href="fizz" class="buzz"></a>` into a `<div id="poo"></div>`

EDIT:
Or alternatively, how can I call a function:

```
boom(var someVar);
```

`boom` is on the new window, and I need to pass `someVar` from the old window to the new window.